# Define a function that filters items from the lazy list of lazy list

Tags: scala, functional-programming, stream

Define a function that filters items from the lazy list of lazy list. The function is supposed to have two parameters: lazy list of lazy lists and number. Only lazy lists whose length is greater than or equal to the specified value are to remain in the result list.

Example:

```scala
lazyfilter(LazyList(LazyList(1,2,3), LazyList(2,3), LazyList(4.5) ), 3 ) 
-> LazyList( LazyList(1,2,3))
```

My attempt :

```scala
def lazyfilter[A](listOfLists: LazyList[LazyList[A]], filter: A): LazyList[LazyList[A]] = {
  listOfLists.filter(_.length.equals(filter))
}

println(lazyfilter(LazyList(LazyList(1,2,3), LazyList(2,3), LazyList(4.5) ), 3 ))
```

Any idea how to do it for greater than or equal of the specified value??

Comment: Just replace `equals` with `>=` ...  Also, type `filter` should be `Int`. As a side note, evaluating length of a `LazyList` seems like a pretty stupid idea :/

Answer (score 1):

Just declare `filter` parameter as `Int`. Also potentially you don't want to evaluate the whole list, taking up to `filter` is enough to filter by length:

```scala
def lazyfilter[A](listOfLists: LazyList[LazyList[A]], filter: Int): LazyList[LazyList[A]] = {
  listOfLists.filter(_.take(filter).length == filter)
}
```